# mysql python doesn't update the table for some reason

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

```
import MySQLdb 
import sys  
connection = MySQLdb.connect (host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "", db = "testdb") 
cursor = connection.cursor () 
cursor.execute ("SELECT message from Messages ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1") 
data = cursor.fetchall() 
cursor.execute ("SELECT ID from Messages ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1") 
number = cursor.fetchall() 
for row in data: 
    message = row[0] 
for row in number: 
    ID = row[0]          
response = "Query received"
ID=str(ID)
cursor.execute ("""UPDATE Messages SET response=%s WHERE ID=%s """,(response,int(ID)))
cursor.close ()
connection.close ()
sys.exit()
```

This is a python script which selects the message properly from the table but doesn't seem to update it
The table has 3 columns ID message and response. I am using python3 and XAMPP server to host the database.

Comment: Update query seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql-update/

1. Connect to the database by creating a new MySQLConnection object.
2. Create a new MySQLCursor object from the MySQLConnection object and call the execute() method of the MySQLCursor object. To accept the changes, you call the commit() method of the MySQLConnection object after calling the execute() method. Otherwise, no changes will be made to the database.
3. Close the cursor and database connection.

Hope this will help you.